# How to find unwanted js files are included in website

Tags: javascript, html

I am having a problem finding all of the unwanted js files that are being included in my website which is why I am not using it.  It's automatically including them when website lunches.  I found the js file url however I'm unable to find it in my project folder.  By the way I'm by using chrome element to inspect the elements of the page.  See results below:

[image]

Comment: You need to find causes, but not fix consequences.

Comment: is there any way to restrict that url?

Answer (score 0):

please check:
i. Go to-->program file-->Elex-tech-->YAC--->click on uninstall and proceed it.

it's help for me

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to a chrome extension you installed, which is fetching those files